# Espresso + RecyclerView - how to wait until all views are ready?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm trying to use `Espresso` to test my application.  One flow that I am testing displays a `RecyclerView` which displays a random amount of `ViewHolder` objects.  For my test, I am trying to click on a specific `ViewHolder` that has the text "Test" displayed in a title `TextView`.

I use the following code to click on the appropriate `ViewHolder`:

```
onView((withId(R.id.recycler_view))).perform(actionOnHolderItem(CustomMatcher.withName(name), click()));
```

Where `CustomMatcher.withName` is:

```
public static Matcher<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> withName(final String name)
{
    return new BoundedMatcher<RecyclerView.ViewHolder, CustomAdapter.VHItem>(CustomAdapter.VHItem.class)
    {
        @Override
        protected boolean matchesSafely(CustomAdapter.VHItem viewHolder)
        {
            return viewHolder.title.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(name);
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description)
        {
            description.appendText("view holder with name: " + name);
        }
    };
}
```

This seems to work, in so much that there are no `Espresso` errors about not being able to find a matching `ViewHolder`, or the `RecyclerView` being searched cannot be found, etc.

However, about 10-15% of the time, the `ViewHolder` is never actually selected.  This means that the view is found but the `click` action does not occur.  I've confirmed that the view is not being clicked via logging to the `onClick` method of the ViewHolder, as shown below:

My `VHItem` class is bound like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(VHItem holder, int position)
{
    String title = mTitles.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(title);
    holder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            showNextScreen();
        }
    });
}
```

So basically the view is found, scrolled to, etc.  But not selected! Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
Zach

Comment: There is an open issue when click becomes long click on slow devices.  Espresso usually prints it into the log. It will look something like "overslept and performed long click" (not exact wording). Did you see something like this?

Comment: I will have to check for that in the log - thanks for the tip.  I've been assigned other work for the time being, and will report back soon.  Thanks!